# Virus infection in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, malware

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.My computer is infected by viruses or malicious software installed without my knowledge during web surfing. I am saying this because whenever I search anything in Google search it is showing me only the error message that we are sorry, we cannot process your request, so I visited the help link provided by Google & tried all the steps instructed there but could not resolve the issue. There I am asked to scan my system because my computer has been affected by some malicious contents.In addition with it I would like to inform that I have installed wine software in order to run Windows application in Ubuntu & installed idm.Can anybody suggest me how do i get rid of this problem.

I installed clamav, scaned the computer using clamscan.
Got the following results

```
/initrd.img.old: Symbolic link
/vmlinuz.old: Symbolic link
/initrd.img: Symbolic link
/vmlinuz: Symbolic link
----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Known viruses: 2424225
Engine version: 0.98.1
Scanned directories: 1
Scanned files: 0
Infected files: 0
Data scanned: 0.00 MB
Data read: 0.00 MB (ratio 0.00:1) 
Time: 4.375 sec (0 m 4 s)
```

yet i don't know whether my problem is resolved or not because it is showing the known viruses 2424225

---

[image: Image posted by OP in comments]

Comment: use clamav to scan viruses

Comment: It's extremely difficult to be infected by such a malware on ubuntu. Seems like a settings problem with your browser. Try using a different browser for google search. Also paste the contents of `/etc/hosts` file here.

Comment: I have tried using chrome,mozilla & default browser of ubuntu but all are showing the same error message

Comment: what is clamav & how do i use that

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? (Upload it to imgur.com and post the link here) Googling the error message turns up a few network- or provider-specific problems, but no actual virus infection.

Comment: yeah sure. this is the link : http://imgur.com/Pw0aYdu

Comment: Problem might be in your local network, not exactly your computer.

May be you are using some proxy or VPN?

Comment: i'm not sure about this, i don't know whether i am using it or not because i am not aware of these terms however is there any solution regarding this issue

Comment: Could you paste information from below commands to http://paste.ubuntu.com/: `route -e`, `ifconfig -a`, `cat /etc/hosts`, `cat /etc/network/interfaces`, `netstat -nputw`

Comment: Before run clamscan you should run `sudo freshclam`, then run `clamscan -r /`. But I think you have nothing to do with antivirus, my bet that problem is in network configuration.

Comment: Did you search for many similar things within a short space of time? Google sometimes gives this message to me when I'm checking out movie releases by year, for example, which is their own built in feature. Pretty dumb, I know, but it's a possible explanation.

Answer (score 7):

First, your ClamAV install shows that there aren't any viruses on your Ubuntu install (The Known Viruses entry simply shows how many Viruses ClamAV has in it's scanning database). Secondly, the reason you're receiving the error with Google is most likely not due to the fact that you have a virus on your Ubuntu install (Linux and GNU user-space works a whole lot differently than Windows (unimportant)), but rather that you have another infected computer on your local network, are using an infected VPN to connect, or your IP was recently changed by your ISP to a previously-malicious address that Google is blocking.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to change your IP, as it may have previously used to host a malicious address that websites will block. If you don't know how to change your IP, look at this guide, [How to change your IP in Ubuntu](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-change-ip-address/), while that guide is for an older version, it should still work. If that doesn't work, call your ISP and ask them to change it for you.